# SOLR NOT doesn't work inside parentheses

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I have a simple query:

```
Type:ABC* AND -Foo:""
```

That works, but if I put parentheses around Foo then it won't work:

```
Type:ABC* AND (-Foo:"")
```

I eventually want to get to:

```
Type:ABC* AND (-Foo:"" OR -Bar:"" OR -FooBar:"")
```

I want to find all records where Type starts with ABC and where any of Foo, Bar, or FooBar have a non empty value.  The fields will exist for all records, but I only want to find where at least one of them is not empty.

Any help would be great.

Comment: try Type:ABC* AND -Foo:("")

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can write/build the query

```
/select?q=Type:ABC*&fq=-Foo:("")



/select?q=Type:ABC*&fq=-Foo:("") OR -Bar:("") OR -FooBar:("")
```